# Find cell based on Date in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a file with a few columns including one with dates and another with some integers.

I want to obtain the row number of a cell based on its date. So in column B, I want the row number of the cell containing the date 31st of December 2018. The display format in the workbook is "31-Dec-2018" and when clicking on the cell it shows 12/31/2018. I tried using

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B500").Find(What:=CDate("Dec. 31, 2018")).Activate
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B500").Find(What:=12/31/2016).Activate
```

But neither works as I get an error "Object Variable not set"). I have been googling a lot and couldn't find a suitable solution which activates the relevant cell. What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim lDate As Date, r As Range
    lDate = DateSerial(2018, 12, 31)
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B500").Find(What:=lDate)
    r.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Simply verify that the data in column **B** are real Excel dates rather than text values that resemble dates.
Creating the range using `FIND()` will permit you to test it **before** you attempt to `Select` it and trap any errors yourself.